# Is there a performance gain in CSS for grouping relating properties under one selector vs two?

Tags: html, css, performance, css-selectors

I'm using SCSS/COMPASS on a project(personal web design framework) and am considering if this way of modularizing code will hinder performance at all.

I want to do this so that I can set my typography in one .scss file and my positioning (for this element and others) in another .scss file. This would allow me to split up my aesthetics from positioning. Good for the way I prefer to think, especially if the website gets bigger. Problem is by doing this, I now am selecting the same element multiple times & in different places.

Would this technique cause issues (page load speed, etc) at any website traffic levels?

Here is the code, I have my font style properties & my positioning properties for my:

```
<header class="header">
    <h1>Title</h1>
</header>
```

split up as follows:

```
header h1 {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    color: navy;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.header h1 {
    margin: 0 0 9.5% 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: CSS selector performance is so negligible you'd be better off removing a single image from the site than you would be to optimize selectors.

Comment: I would say having them combined would save on file size, but instead I'll leave you with something to think about... Premature optimisation is the root of all evil.

Comment: the browser won't even care. why would you ? :D

Comment: I would think that during development, it would be easiest to have as few style rules as possible for any given element. That way, you'd only have to check in one place if there's something you need to change. At least that's my preference; other people's may differ.